# DIV / Table Headers are on bottom, jSON data is on top?

Tags: jquery, html, css, json

I cant seem to figure this one out. I have tried various of things with no luck. Any ideas on how to resolve this?

I have attached a link for a screenshot of what I am getting...

http://s23.postimg.org/4eu3mhmyj/Capture.png

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading clearfix">
          <h4 class="panel-title pull-left" style="padding-top: px;">Counts</h4>
                      <form method="POST" action="">
                     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-right" name="reset"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span></button>
            </form>
        </div>
          <table class="table">
          <thead>
             <div> <tr>
                  <th>Count</th>
                  <th>Item</th>
              </tr>
              </div>

    <tbody> 
             <div id="JSON_output" class="row"> 
                            </div>
                        </tbody>
                                <script type="text/javascript">
      jQuery.ajax({
                     type: "GET",
                     url: "json.php",
                     dataType: "json",
                     success: function(response){
                        $.each(response, function(key, value){
                            var html = '' +
                                '<tr><td><ul>'+value.count+'</ul></th>'+
                                '<td><ul><ul><ul>'+value.item+'</ul></ul></ul></td></tr>'+
                                '';
                            $("#JSON_output").append(html);
                        });
                        }
                        });
                </script>


         </thead>      
        </table>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Can't really see the image. And also, adding css will help us to trace your problem. I think your problem is with css. Did you also try inspecting the output html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your JSON output from a DIV to a TBody should help you out.

```
<div> <tr>
                  <th>Count</th>
                  <th>Item</th>
              </tr>
              </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve it. Had to change the JSON output from a div to a Tbody. :)

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: @leesei Why so? It looks like the OP has found the answer to his question.